# Video source link grabbing

Tags: java, javascript, php, nginx

**Hello.**

I have a problem with video source link.
On my website i have my own video player and i want to play movies in this player thats why I need video source link.

I have made script in PHP which retrieve video source url from html code. So I put htXtp://www.cda.pl/video/16942690/Uderz-ja-Reakcja-dzieci this code and on field in my site then my script grabbed video source url http://vsbg012.cda.pl/14204991293875.mp4?st=VOOh7w9RbwazMsCO9bP5pg&e=1420688920 to database and everything were fine. Video was playing on my video player.

After 3 hours I wanted do display this same movie from my site and then information appeared ‘The requested video is not found’.To see what happened, I went to this link htXtp://www.cda.pl/video/16942690/Uderz-ja-Reakcja-dzieci myself and checked html code on browser. It turned out that the video source url was changed! From this first above to this  http://vsbg012.cda.pl/14204991293875.mp4?st=L1l4-FwEx1DQT4zvMaMy1w&e=1420752870 . If you put video source link to brower then appear ‘401 Forbidden nginx’. Before in this same link was playing video on player.

So thats mean they have some mechanism which generate links video source for every session or dynamically generate links with access token or it is part of some mechanism of server– I dont know.

**1.**  I want to know what is that mechanism and how it called?
**2.**  Is there possibilty to grab dynamically video source url to my site?

Its normal when I put video source url on my database its static and stored. But I was wondering about that, when someone click on my video to play then -> programming language will grab dynamically video source url from normal link like that htXtp://www.cda.pl/video/16942690/Uderz-ja-Reakcja-dzieci and store it or database( ornot if not needed) -> video will play.

**3.**  What tools and programming language should I use to do that script please give me advice and tips.

Thanks for any help

Comment: sounds like the video site is "defective by design". sometimes the offered embed code uses "permalinks" that the main UI doesn't...

Comment: read there terms of service and docs for sharing/embeds if any

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after wasting alot of time I found that 'e=time+date in secs' see this link : http://currentmillis.com/ to convert current time and date to seconds. And for the other parameter 'st' still dont have a clueclue..